# Keras replace log(0) in custom loss function

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I am trying to use Poisson unscaled deviance as a loss function for my neural network, but there's a major flow with this : `y_true` can take (and will take very often) the value `0`.

Unscaled deviance works like this for Poisson case :

If `y_true = 0`, then `loss = 2 * d * y_pred`

If `y_true > 0`, then `loss = 2 * d *y_pred * (y_true * log(y_true)-y_true * log(y_pred)-y_true+y_pred`

Note that as soon as `log(0)` is computed, the loss becomes `-inf` so my goal is to prevent this to happen.

I tried using the switch function to solve this but here's the trick: 
If I have the value `log(0)`, I don't want to replace it by `0` (with `K.zeros()`) because it would be considering that `y_true = 1` since `log(1) = 0`.
Therefore I want to try using a large negative value in this case (`-10000` for example) but I don't know how to do this since `K.variable(-10000)` gives the error:

```
ValueError: Rank of `condition` should be less than or equal to rank of `then_expression` and `else_expression`. ndim(condition)=1, ndim(then_expression)=0
```

Using `K.zeros_like(y_true)` instead of `K.variable(-10000)` will work for keras but it is mathematically incorrect and the optimisation doesn't work properly because of this.

I'd like to know how to replace the log by a large negative value in the switch function. Here's my attempt:

```py
def custom_loss3(data, y_pred):
    y_true = data[:, 0]
    d = data[:, 1]
    # condition
    loss_value = KB.switch(KB.less_equal(y_true, 0),
                           2 * d * y_pred, 2 * d * (y_true * KB.switch(KB.less_equal(y_true, 0),
                           KB.variable(-10000), KB.log(y_true)) - y_true * KB.switch(KB.less_equal(y_pred, 0.), KB.variable(-10000), KB.log(y_pred)) - y_true + y_pred))
    return loss_value
```

Comment: Your attempt looks good, I'd suggest you just try it out. Note that $0 \log 0 \to 0$, thus you can check for small values before the condition and return the appropriate value.

Comment: Another attempt would be to scale your data by y+1, so you have values in 1 and 2, respectively.

Comment: You know that `KB.less_equal()` broadcasts vector, right? You want to apply the condition individually to each element in `y_pred`, is it so?

Comment: @Vlad I didn't know that i'm pretty knew to keras. Indeed I want to try them individually. What should I use then ? The goal is to check whether y_true = 0 so i can apply the appropriate function.

Comment: @ThomasLang y is between 0 and 180 (actually 180 is kind of an outlier but most of my data is between 0 and 1. Aktough i still have to consider higher values so i don't think i can do that.